# Uniqueness of _id within a shard

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm looking into sharding using mongodb, and most if it is rather straight forward. I have some experience with sharding in other databases, so I'm not asking about the concept itself. There's one thing I'm confused by, and there doesn't seem to be anything in the documentation about this, so here goes.

Is `_id` required to be unique within the shard, regardless of shard key?

A small scale (single shard) test seems to confirm that this is the case. It does however seem like a less than stellar approach to sharding, which has me confused. To me it would make more sense to require `shard-key` + `_id` to be unique (i.e. use a compound key), or you'll have inconsistent behavior depending on where your shard-keys end up being routed to. My data model uses deterministic keys, and the shard key is an intrinsic part of it. So I guess it comes down to, did I do something wrong in my small scale test? Do I need to store the shard-key twice, once as a shard-key field and once as part of `_id`? Or is there some special case where I can somehow declare a compound key using `shard-key` and `_id`?

**Update**

For completeness, this is the trivial case I'm testing, inserting the following two documents:

```
{"_id": 1, "shardkey": 1}
{"_id": 1, "shardkey": 2}
```

First one obviously goes through, second one fails. If I would've had two shards, and the shard keys would've been routed to different shards, I assume both would've succeeded.

I can obviously just combine the shard-key and the id to create the `_id` field for mongodb, since this is really the key I'm using, but it seems like a weird way to approach the problem from a database architectural standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

_id needs to be unique, always, whether the collection is sharded or not.  The shard key does not need to be unique.  It is used to split the collection into chunks which can be split onto the shards making up the database.  The shard key needs to provide enough granularity to split the documents in the collection into chunks.  Its obviously a good idea to link the shard key to how you query the data, and use a shard key which relates to the fields that you query on.  This way the queries you run will be easily directed to the relevant shards to satisfy the query.  If the shard key isnt selective enough then the query will need to go to multiple shards to find the correct documents.  You can create a compound index on _id + shard-key and make it unique if you want.

I realise this doesnt fully answer the question. tbh I am struggling to understand what you're asking.  Perhaps if you could post an example of the documents you're storing and the queries you're running it would help.

Comment: Apparently, _id doesn't technically need to be unique, only within the shard. The way mongodb seems to handle it is to force _id to be globally unique or otherwise there's trouble ahead. It doesn't enforce this uniqueness constraint however, and an easy way to do that (and indeed what other databases do) is to define the key as shard-key + id, but it appears mongodb doesn't do this (and that's my question, is that really the case? They leave it to the application to enforce?). I'm not asking about an index, a unique index on shard-key + _id is superfluous if _id has to be globally unique.